# Есть ли в Android аналог виджета ColorDialog из Delphi?

Tags: java, android

Нужно создать меню выбора цвета из палитры. В Delphi есть ColorDialog. Может в Android есть подобное, но пока не нашел. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: [тысячи их](https://www.google.ru/search?q=android+color+picker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [Color picker](https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker) из github

Answer (score 2):

В Android нет ничего подобного, то же самое с OpenDialog и SaveDialog, нужно либо воспользоваться какой-то из сторонних библиотек, либо реализовать самому на базе `Activity` или `AlertDialog`.